# multicore nodejs game server

Tags: node.js, distributed

I'm developing a card game backend with nodejs, I'm using socket.io and Redis as an adaptor so different instances can access to all sockets.

I'm planning to save match states which might be between 5 to 10 KB in Redis and while players in a match might be connected to different instances when each one of them performs an action, their instance will update match state in Redis.

it seems to be ok but I feel it has some problems, for example, in case of any crash or restarts I need to fetch all matches and do some actions on them but how to make each instance handle a part of matches?
also, I will start a timer for the next player while it might be connected to a different instance so when they play their turn it will handle in another instance and can't stop the timer because the timer was started in another instance!

I think if I could have an instance in charge of a specific match it would solve most of my problems but I don't know how to achieve it.

any advice or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to follow the exact problem here, but you should be able to create an highly available system, that will allow you to not restart from scratch.

1. Use an high available Redis instance, for example using [Redis Sentinel](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel), or Redis Cloud instances that provide HA
2. Using Node JS Socket.io you can also deploy it on many server (backed by Redis),take a look to https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#Using-Node-JS-Cluster

This should allow you to have an "alway-on" architecture that can scale.